# save svg as png same media query (responsive) and same css rules

Tags: html, css, svg, media-queries, png

I have   small svg and I was able to save it ,
 But i need to save the same css rules :  media query and font family 
when i change the sceen size i can see the color changing
but i need also the same css rules when downloading the png, 
  How to do it?

Here is the code:

@Gilad

```
    <svg width="100" height="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="5" fill="yellow" />
       </svg>

    <button id="btn">Sava/download as Png</button>

    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

here is the script

```
     var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    function triggerDownload (imgURI) {
      var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,
        bubbles: false,
        cancelable: true
      });

      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.setAttribute('download', 'IMAGE.png');
      a.setAttribute('href', imgURI);
      a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

      a.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    $("#btn").click(function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
        var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
        var img = new Image();
        var svgBlob = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' });
        var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
        img.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            var imgURI = canvas
                .toDataURL('image/png')
                .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');
           triggerDownload(imgURI);
        };
        $("svg").hide();

       img.src = url;
```

here is style:

```
     circle {
        fill: green;
    }

    @media (min-width: 400px) {
        circle {
            fill: blue;
        }
    }
```